# CSS boxshadow over an image

Tags: html, css

I want to place `boxshadow` on an image. I'm trying following but it just adds it behind the image, making it not visible. How that can be done?

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
    .box2 {
        float: left;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="box2"><img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/502/18386328915_c63c4f6c7f_q.jpg" /></div>
```

**Problem:**

[image]

**JSFiddle Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Lwm95h7q/

Comment: if u only need to add outline you can try `border:10px solid #f00;`

Comment: @Dimple I need to add the border inside the div, not outside. so that doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: then try this: `outline: 10px solid #f00;
   outline-offset:-10px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `:after`, for example.

```
.box1{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.box2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
}

.box2:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Take a look at the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/Lwm95h7q/5/

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `box-shadow` with 
`outline: 10px solid #f00;outline-offset:-10px;`

```css
.box1{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.box2 {
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
   outline: 10px solid #f00;
   outline-offset:-10px;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">some text</div>

<div class="box2"><img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/502/18386328915_c63c4f6c7f_q.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: This gets my vote, it's a lot simpler and cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using an `:after` pseudo element with the `box-shadow` over the top of the `img`:

- Add `position: relative;` to `.box2` to allow the pseudo element to be positioned relatively to it
- Add `.box2:after` with `position: absolute;` to take it out of the document flow. Set the `height` and `width` equal to the `height` and `width` of `.box2` and position it to the `top` and `left` of `.box2`. Apply the `box-shadow` to this

```css
.box1 {
  background: green;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
.box2 {
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.box2:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
  content: "";
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">some text</div>
<div class="box2">
  <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/502/18386328915_c63c4f6c7f_q.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not given padding so.. add this css

```
  .box2 {
float: left;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px 10px  #f00;
 padding: 10px;
    }
```